# My unit test case is failing when I'm trying to match an input string with a RegEx

Tags: regex, typescript, unit-testing

I have written a Typescript function  to check an input string for these allowed characters: a-z A-Z - , . ' space

And I am testing this function using my unit test case and this unit test case is failing.

Typescript function to check input string for allowed characters:

```
public static containsAllowedCharacters = (input: string, pattern: RegExp): boolean => {
        return pattern.test(input);
    }
```

Unit test case that is testing this and failing:

```
describe('containsAllowedCharacters function ', () => {
        it('Should return true if input string contains allowed characters ', () => {
            let input = "full";
            let pattern = new RegExp("/[a-z][A-Z]-.,' /");
            let result = BusinessRulesUtil.containsAllowedCharacters(input, pattern)
            expect(result).to.be.true;
        });
    });
```

My unit test case is failing - seeing an assertion error in my test file

Error:

```
expected null to be true
    AssertionError@test/
```

Comment: What's the rule of allowing/rejecting your strings?

Comment: Don't add `/` delimiters when calling `new RegExp`. Best to avoid `new RegExp` entirely - use regex literal instead, whenever possible. I'm sure there's a canonical for this

Comment: I think you meant to allow all those characters you've written, but you've incorrectly placed them outside charset. Change your pattern declaration line to this `let pattern = /^[a-zA-Z.,' -]+$/`

Comment: Thanks @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Your solution worked!

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Not using ```new RegExp``` worked! Thank you!